Problem Grub Ubuntu
I have Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop installed on an NVMe drive with an ext4 file system. This is the only OS I have installed, however, when I try to load it, it jumps me directly to the minimal bash-like line editing is supported screen.
Looking for my drive where I have the /boot partition, I found that I have it on hd5, msdos3.
I then do:
grub> set root=(hd5,3)
grub> set prefix=(hd5,3)/boot/grub
grub> insmod normal
grub> normal

Then I get the error:
invalid environment block error

Then an Ubuntu interface that says Checking file system loads and the screen turns black.
Can anyone give me an idea where to go? Thank you all for your patience.

Are you sure your disk is not broken? Is Windows installed on the same disk?

You've added version (22.04) but not type (or product), ie. Server? Desktop? flavor? etc..   I'd suggest booting live media and checking drive health (using drives SMART capabilities; ie. is the drive failing thus your problem etc..) then perform file-system checks if the drive itself is healthy (commands to perform this vary on file-system & you gave no clues here), as if problems are detected & fixed, you'll likely have a normal boot on next try (assuming hardware is all good).

I have edited the post. Thanks for the help

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/s3CVV9SGzT/

Thanks for the help

Remove all USB sticks and other devices from which your computer might boot.

Do not know RAID, nor LVM. It looks like you have UEFI boot from RAID on NVMe drives &  LVM on sda thru sdd in old MBR(msdos) partitioning. While Ubuntu allows UEFI on MBR, gpt is preferred for UEFI boot, by UEFI. But now conversion from MBR to gpt will totally erase drive(s), so not recommended unless totally redoing everything after backups. Is system set to boot in UEFI mode?

Do you mean at the bios level?

What surprises me is that it doesn't let me mount the nvme with the live cd, it gives me the typical busy error but I can't access it either

I was looking at the topic of mounting the nvme raid, which is in /boot, and I just came across these errors

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/26w4kc9nHd/

In the end I cleaned the system but I still couldn't find the boot, so I broke the raid and recovered the information and reinstalled the system. Thanks to all for the help
